Two processes with the same law, their supremum?
Suppose that there are two continuous-time processes $X = (X_t)$ and $Y = (Y_t)$ with $t \geq 0$, they have the same law under probability measure $P$. Could we say that $\sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1}(X_t)$ and $\sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1}(Y_t)$ also have the same law?
It seems very intuitive, but the solution looks complicated (indicating only the case for continuous processes and giving a $Q$-intersect with counting sequence).

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

What is meant by "they have the same law"? If you are talking about continuous time processes having the same joint CDF for any finite collection of times, the answer is "no" unless there are some additional properties such as continuity of sample paths. If you are talking about discrete time processes the answer would change to "yes."

I think I mean the former, i.e talking about continuous time. If I add the continuity of sample paths, then would it be true?

Suppose we consider general random processes $X_t$ and $Y_t$ defined for $t\geq 0$ such that for all positive integers $n$ and all times $t_1, ..., t_n \in [0, \infty)$, the joint distributions of $(X_{t_1}, ..., X_{t_n})$ and $(Y_{t_1}, ..., Y_{t_n})$ are the same.
Right-continuity assumption: Suppose the sample paths of $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are surely real-valued and right-continuous over all $t \in [0, \infty)$. Then  $\sup_{t\in [0,1]}\{X_t\}$ and $\sup_{t\in [0,1]} \{Y_t\}$ are both valid extended random variables (possibly taking infinite values), and they both have the same distribution.
Proof: Let $\{t_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be a listing of all rational numbers in $[0,1]$. Fix $z\in\mathbb{R}$.  By right-continuity of $X_t$ and $Y_t$ we have
$$ \left\{\left(\sup_{t\in [0,1]} \{X_t\}\right)\leq z\right\} =\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}\{X_{t_i}\leq z\}$$
$$ \left\{\left(\sup_{t\in [0,1]} \{Y_t\}\right)\leq z\right\} =\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}\{Y_{t_i}\leq z\}$$
It follows that both of these are valid events, as they are a countable intersection of events. By continuity of probability
\begin{align}
P[\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}\{X_{t_i}\leq z\}] &= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P[\cap_{i=1}^n\{X_{t_i}\leq z\}]\\
&\overset{(a)}{=}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P[\cap_{i=1}^n\{Y_{t_i}\leq z\}]\\
&=P[\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}\{Y_{t_i}\leq z\}]
\end{align}
where step (a) uses the fact that $(X_{t_1}, ..., X_{t_n})$ and $(Y_{t_1}, ..., Y_{t_n})$ have the same distribution.
$\Box$
Counter-example without right-continuity: Let $U$ be a random variable that takes values in $[0,1]$ and is distributed uniformly over that interval.
Define $X_t$ and $Y_t$ for all $t\in [0, \infty)$ by
\begin{align}
X_t &= 0 \\
Y_t &= \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
0 & \mbox{if $t \neq U$} \\
1 & \mbox{if $t=U$} 
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
Then $P[Y_t=0]=1$ for all $t \in [0, \infty)$. Therefore, for all positive integers $n$ and all times $t_1,..., t_n \in [0, \infty)$ we have
$$P[\cap_{i=1}^n\{X_{t_i}=0\}]=P[\cap_{i=1}^n\{Y_{t_i}=0\}]=1$$
However, we surely have
$$ \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \{X_t\}=0$$
$$\sup_{t \in [0,1]}\{Y_t\}=1$$
